# How does this work? (C++ name lookup magic)

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

I've been looking at [cereal](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal) and [boost::serialization](https://github.com/boostorg/serialization) code to understand how class registration works, but can't understand few moments.

Here's my understanding what happens:

- I request an explicit instantiation of `static_object<magic<B№>>`.
- There's a call to `adl_magic` in constructor, which causes compiler to instantiate all of its overloads.
- Because return type of some of those overloads refers to `typename instantiator<inserter<A№, T>>::type`, compiler makes an instance`instantiator` (no pun intended).
- Now, I don't understand what happens next. Why does it instantiate `static_object<nserter<A№, T>>`, even though it is referenced from inside of a function that is never called? And why `dummy` is required (and why different compilers need different one)? And why it doesn't work if I replace `typename instantiator<inserter<A№, T>>::type` with `typename static_object<inserter<A№, T>>::type`?

The rest of the code seems fairly obvious to me.

```
template<typename T>
class static_object {
    static void use(T const&) {}

    static T& ref;
    static T& create()
    {
        static T object;
        use(ref);  // why it doesn't work without this line?
        return object;
    }

public:
    static T& instance() { return create(); }
};
template <class T>
T& static_object<T>::ref = static_object<T>::create();



template <void(*)()> struct instantiate_function {};

template<typename T>
struct instantiator {
    static void instantiate() { static_object<T>::instance(); }

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    virtual void dummy() { instantiate(); }
#else
    using dummy = instantiate_function<instantiate>;
#endif
};

#include <string>
#include <vector>
// This gets called when stuff below is instantiated
using list = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
using list = static_object<std::vector<string_pair>>;
template<typename A, typename B>
struct inserter {
    inserter()
    {
        list::instance().push_back(std::pair{A::name, B::name});
    }
};

// These are just some structs for demonstration.
struct A1 { static const char name[]; }; const char A1::name[] = "A1";
struct A2 { static const char name[]; }; const char A2::name[] = "A2";
struct B1 { static const char name[]; }; const char B1::name[] = "B1";
struct B2 { static const char name[]; }; const char B2::name[] = "B2";
struct B3 { static const char name[]; }; const char B3::name[] = "B3";

// I've omitted an "adl_tag" argument, which is needed to make 
// sure ADL finds all overloads
template<typename T> void adl_magic(T*, int) {}

// each of these would be behind some REGISTER_ARCHIVE(A) macro
template<typename T> typename instantiator<inserter<A1, T>>::type adl_magic(T*, A1*);
template<typename T> typename instantiator<inserter<A2, T>>::type adl_magic(T*, A2*);

template<typename T>
struct magic {
    magic()
    {
        adl_magic(static_cast<T*>(nullptr), 0);
    }
};

// each of these would be behind some REGISTER_CLASS(B) macro
template struct static_object<magic<B1>>;
template struct static_object<magic<B2>>;
template struct static_object<magic<B3>>;

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    for(auto& p : list::instance())
        std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
}
```

---

EDIT: If I change corresponding declarations above with these, they appear to work with all compilers. I don't understand why they work, but I think they do because `auto` forces instantiation of `static_object<T>` to deduce type.

```
template<typename T>
struct instantiator {
    static auto instantiate() { return static_object<T>::instance(); }
};

template<typename T> decltype(instantiator<inserter<A1, T>>::instantiate()) adl_magic(T*, A1*);
template<typename T> decltype(instantiator<inserter<A2, T>>::instantiate()) adl_magic(T*, A2*);
```

There is another variation, which works only with GCC and not other compilers:

```
template<typename T>
struct instantiator {
    static T& ref;
};
template<typename T>
T& instantiator<T>::ref = static_object<T>::instance();

template<typename T> decltype(instantiator<inserter<A1, T>>::ref) adl_magic(T*, A1*);
template<typename T> decltype(instantiator<inserter<A2, T>>::ref) adl_magic(T*, A2*);
```

Comment: Your question seems very hard to parse because there seem to be 8 question marks (right, or did I miss another?), and a lot of code. I recommend trying to write a small compilable example and provide a minimum amount of question marks.

Comment: It is the smallest compilable example, if you combine all code blocks into one.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb, I've combined the code into one block, and reduced amount of question marks. I hope it is easier (and not harder) to parse now.

Comment: `dummy` seems needed to enforce code emitting then object creation; this needs template instantiations. This code is very tricky indeed...

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I don't understand what happens next. Why does it instantiate static_object>, even though it is referenced from inside of a function that is never called?

The instantiation happens because `::type` needs to look into that class template specialization, so it has to instantiate it.

> And why dummy is required (and why different compilers need different one)?

Can't answer the parenthesized part, but `dummy` references `instantiate`, whereas nothing else does. Something has to reference `instantiate`, so that the compiler compiles the code therein. A virtual member function of a class template is always instantiated even if unused, so that does the trick. The `using` alias passes the address of the function to another template which triggers the compiler to compile `instantiate` aswell.

> And why it doesn't work if I replace typename instantiator>::type with typename static_object>::type?

Because then you have instantiated `static_object<T>`, but that only instantiates declarations of member functions (such as virtual member functions or using aliases) and static data member declarations and such. Not member function bodies. Therefore, it wouldn't trigger the instantiation of the static data member *definition* of `static_object<...>`, therefore it won't create an object of `T`, therefore it wouldn't extend `list`.

> ```
>  use(ref);  // why it doesn't work without this line?
> ```

Because `instantiate` references `static_object<T>::instance` references `static_object<T>::create` references... `ref` by passing it to `use`. If that last thing is removed, nothing requires the existence of `ref` anymore, so its definition won't be instantiated.